# Can I tell Beamer that `\uncover` should be invisible, not merely grayed out?

Tags: beamer

In Beamer, I'm using `\uncover` because I want the omitted text to take up space.  But I *don't* want the grayed-out default rendering.  Is there a way to use `\uncover`, or an equivalent, that will take up the same space as the text but be completely invisible when rendered?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The default setting of beamer is `invisible` for uncovered text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello World!

\uncover<2->{Example Text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe your scheme changes the default to `transparent`. You can set up the behavior by:

```
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
```

---

See section 17.6 “Transparency Effects” in the [beamer manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more details about the appearance of covered elements.

Comment: How can I cover and uncover a code listing?